# Infinispan drops connection to MYSQL 5.7 database

Tags: java, mysql, keycloak, infinispan

We have Keycloak in HA, which we have configured with a external Infinispan cluster for sessions, clientSessions & authenticationSessions.
Everything works under containers in a similar approach like the one performed under https://github.com/albertoSoto/keycloak-infinispan-cluster

The project runs KC 15.0.2 with Wildfly (migration to quarkus to be done), and in that case, uses Infinispan 11.0.9 to perform the external data persistence to Mysql 5.7. The driver used is the latest one, using  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.28/mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar as suggested by Oracle. The connection driver is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.

The project starts nice, but after random time, mysql drops the connection and the Infinispan cluster can't reconnect.

In a trial to make it work, I have been able to use Agroal configuration, based in a properties file like it's at the bottom of this message.

The content of that agroal property file, that overrides JPA behavior in the project is the following:

```
org.infinispan.agroal.metricsEnabled=false
org.infinispan.agroal.minSize=10
org.infinispan.agroal.maxSize=100
org.infinispan.agroal.initialSize=20
org.infinispan.agroal.acquisitionTimeout_s=1
org.infinispan.agroal.validationTimeout_m=1
org.infinispan.agroal.leakTimeout_s=10
org.infinispan.agroal.reapTimeout_m=10
org.infinispan.agroal.maxLifetime_m=10
org.infinispan.agroal.autoCommit=true
org.infinispan.agroal.jdbcTransactionIsolation=READ_COMMITTED
org.infinispan.agroal.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/infinispan
org.infinispan.agroal.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
org.infinispan.agroal.principal=keycloak
org.infinispan.agroal.credential=password
```

The error shown after the connection is closed from the db is the following:

```
[1;31m21:55:31,052 ERROR (jgroups-319,vi-infinispan-1-5379) [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] ISPN000136: Error executing command RemoveCommand on Cache 'clientSessions', writing keys [WrappedByteArray{bytes=0304090000000E\j\a\v\a\.\u\t\i\l\.\U\U\I\DBC9903F798\m85\/000000020000000C\l\e\a\s\t\S\i\g\B\i\t\s\$000000000B\m\o\s\t\S\i\g\B\i\t\s\$00168D0C\z8AB49FBA9B\C118A06A0DB\D82... (85 bytes), hashCode=73644551}] org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from vi-infinispan-0-53111, see cause for remote stack trace
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidSingleResponseCollector.withException(ValidSingleResponseCollector.java:37)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidSingleResponseCollector.addResponse(ValidSingleResponseCollector.java:21)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.addResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.onResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:43)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.RequestRepository.addResponse(RequestRepository.java:52)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1402)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processMessage(JGroupsTransport.java:1305)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.access$300(JGroupsTransport.java:131)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport$ChannelCallbacks.up(JGroupsTransport.java:1445)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:784)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:913)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG3.up(FRAG3.java:165)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:343)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:343)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:876)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:243)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.deliverMessage(UNICAST3.java:1049)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.addMessage(UNICAST3.java:772)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:753)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:405)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:592)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:132)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FailureDetection.up(FailureDetection.java:186)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:254)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:281)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:300)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1396)
    at org.jgroups.util.SubmitToThreadPool$SingleMessageHandler.run(SubmitToThreadPool.java:87)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: Error while removing string keys from database
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:234)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:42)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:728)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:709)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:358)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.BytesObjectInput.readObject(BytesObjectInput.java:32)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.responses.ExceptionResponse$Externalizer.readObject(ExceptionResponse.java:49)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.responses.ExceptionResponse$Externalizer.readObject(ExceptionResponse.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:728)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:709)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:358)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:192)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

We do use JDBC_PING for the cluster connection and 2 nodes are active. They register themselves properly and everything works like a charm, until the timeout is set.

The base configuration that I have placed is the following:

```
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:11.0 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-11.0.xsd
                            urn:infinispan:server:11.0 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-server-11.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:11.0"
        xmlns:server="urn:infinispan:server:11.0">
    <!--
    Generic XML definition located under
    https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/11.0/configdocs/
    -->
    <jgroups>
        <stack-file name="default-udp" path="default-jgroups.xml"/>
        <stack-file name="default-tcp" path="default-jgroups-tcp.xml"/>
        <stack-file name="gce" path="default-jgroups-google.xml"/>
        <stack-file name="k8s" path="default-jgroups-kubernetes.xml"/>
        <stack-file name="kc-udp" path="default-keycloak-jgroups-udp.xml"/>
        <stack-file name="custom-k8s-jdbc" path="custom-jgroups-kubernetes-jdbc.xml"/>
        <stack-file name="custom-tcp-jdbc" path="custom-jgroups-tcp-jdbc.xml"/>
    </jgroups>
    <cache-container name="default" statistics="${env.INFINISPAN_CACHE_STATISTICS:false}">
        <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.commons.GenericJBossMarshaller">
            <white-list>
                <class>java.util.UUID</class>
                <regex>org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.*</regex>
            </white-list>
        </serialization>
        <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller">
            <white-list>
                <class>java.util.UUID</class>
                <regex>org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.*</regex>
            </white-list>
        </serialization>
        <transport cluster="${infinispan.cluster.name:cluster}" stack="${infinispan.cluster.stack:default-udp}"
                   node-name="${infinispan.node.name:}"/>
        <replicated-cache-configuration name="sessions-cfg" mode="SYNC" start="EAGER"
                                        statistics="${env.INFINISPAN_CACHE_STATISTICS:false}">
            <state-transfer timeout="${infinispan.statetransfer.timeout:600000}"/>
            <encoding media-type="application/x-jboss-marshalling"/>
            <expiration lifespan="900000000000000000"/>
        </replicated-cache-configuration>
        <distributed-cache-configuration name="distributed-cache-cfg">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-jboss-marshalling"/>
            <expiration lifespan="900000000000000000"/>
            <persistence passivation="false">
                <string-keyed-jdbc-store shared="true" xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:11.0">

                    <connection-pool properties-file="${env.PROPERTIES_FILE:/opt/infinispan/server/conf/connection-pool.properties}" />
                    <string-keyed-table drop-on-exit="false"
                                        prefix="ISPN">
                        <id-column name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                        <!-- Blob generates error on KC. We increase it to a safe max size (65K per row)
                        <data-column name="DATA_COLUMN" type="BLOB" />
                        -->
                        <data-column name="DATA_COLUMN" type="VARBINARY(50000)"/>
                        <timestamp-column name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT"/>
                        <segment-column name="SEGMENT_COLUMN" type="INT"/>
                    </string-keyed-table>
                </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </persistence>
            <state-transfer timeout="${infinispan.statetransfer.timeout:600000}"/>
        </distributed-cache-configuration>
        <!--https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#distributed-caches_clustered-caches-->
        <!--https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#configuring-jdbc-cache-stores_persistence-->
        <distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="2" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">

        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="clientSessions" owners="2" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="2" configuration="distributed-cache-cfg">
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <!-- Original at v11 -  -->
    <server xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:11.0">
        <interfaces>
            <interface name="public">
                <inet-address value="${infinispan.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
            </interface>
        </interfaces>
        <socket-bindings default-interface="public" port-offset="0">
            <socket-binding name="default" port="11222"/>
        </socket-bindings>
        <security>
            <security-realms>
                <security-realm name="default">
                    <properties-realm groups-attribute="Roles">
                        <user-properties path="users.properties" relative-to="infinispan.server.config.path"
                                         plain-text="true"/>
                        <group-properties path="groups.properties" relative-to="infinispan.server.config.path"/>
                    </properties-realm>
                </security-realm>
            </security-realms>
        </security>
        <endpoints socket-binding="default" security-realm="default">
            <hotrod-connector name="hotrod">
                <authentication>
                    <sasl mechanisms="SCRAM-SHA-512 SCRAM-SHA-384 SCRAM-SHA-256 SCRAM-SHA-1 DIGEST-SHA-512 DIGEST-SHA-384 DIGEST-SHA-256 DIGEST-SHA DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN"
                          qop="auth" server-name="infinispan"/>
                </authentication>
            </hotrod-connector>
            <rest-connector name="rest">
                <authentication mechanisms="DIGEST BASIC"/>
            </rest-connector>
        </endpoints>
    </server>
</infinispan>
```

The thing is... what are am I doing wrong?
There is not too much information about it. Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think you have stumbled across a bug with the persistence availability check that prevents stores from reconnecting if an exception is thrown [ISPN-13863](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-13863). I have just created a PR, however the fix will only be available in the Infinispan 14.x stream.

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan! It's a pity, but luckily is not in our side. Do you know if changing to H2 or Postgre will have the same effect? Do you recommend it?

Comment: I don't think it will help as all of our Infinispan ConnectionFactory#getConnection implementations wrap any SQLException thrown by the DB driver in a PersistenceException. Consequently, BaseJdbcStore#isAvailable doesn't catch the exception and ISPN-13863 occurs.